# How do I access these array keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 5 indexed arrays in an object and I want to access these array keys to display them.

I understand that the last two lines are causing issues. I've searched for an hour and haven't found why it doesnt work.

```js
var quotes = {
  karamazov: [{
    "Serge Karamazov": "Barrez vous **** de mimes."
  }],
  abitbol: [{
    name: "Georges Abitbol",
    quote: "Le train de tes injures roule sur le rail de mon indifférence.",
  }, ],
  bath: [{
    name: "Hubert Bonisseur de la Bath",
    quote: "Ça ne prenait pas beaucoup plus de temps.",
  }, ],
  moulinier: [{
    name: "Moulinier ",
    quote: "L'habit ne fait pas le moine, mais il fait l'agent... Même non titularisé.",
  }, ],
  welles: [{
    name: "Orson Welles",
    quote: "C'est du vol et du plagiat. j'aime pas trop les voleurs et...",
  }, ],
};

const quotesWrap = document.querySelector('#quotes-wrap');

Object.keys(quotes).forEach(function(writer) {
  const citationWrap = document.createElement("div");
  quotesWrap.appendChild(citationWrap);
  const citation = document.createElement("p");
  const auteur = document.createElement("p");
  citationWrap.appendChild(citation);
  citationWrap.appendChild(auteur);

  citationWrap.classList.add("quote");
  citation.classList.add("citation");
  auteur.classList.add("auteur");

  citation.innerHTML = '"' + writer.quote + '"';
  auteur.innerHTML = writer.name;
});
```

```html
<div id="quotes-wrap"></div>
```

Comment: To access the keys of the arrays in your object, you need to iterate over the arrays within each key.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var quotes = {
  karamazov: [{
    "Serge Karamazov": "Barrez vous **** de mimes."
  }],
  abitbol: [{
    name: "Georges Abitbol",
    quote: "Le train de tes injures roule sur le rail de mon indifférence.",
  }, ],
  bath: [{
    name: "Hubert Bonisseur de la Bath",
    quote: "Ça ne prenait pas beaucoup plus de temps.",
  }, ],
  moulinier: [{
    name: "Moulinier ",
    quote: "L'habit ne fait pas le moine, mais il fait l'agent... Même non titularisé.",
  }, ],
  welles: [{
    name: "Orson Welles",
    quote: "C'est du vol et du plagiat. j'aime pas trop les voleurs et...",
  }, ],
};

const quotesWrap = document.querySelector('#quotes-wrap');

Object.keys(quotes).forEach(function(writer) {
      const citationWrap = document.createElement("div");
      quotesWrap.appendChild(citationWrap);
      const citation = document.createElement("p");
      const auteur = document.createElement("p");
      citationWrap.appendChild(citation);
      citationWrap.appendChild(auteur);
      citationWrap.classList.add("quote");
      citation.classList.add("citation");
      auteur.classList.add("auteur");

      // array of quotes for each writer
      quotes[writer].forEach(function(quoteObj) {
        // key (author's name) and value (quote) from the quote object
        const authorName = Object.keys(quoteObj)[0];
        const quote = quoteObj[authorName];
        citation.innerHTML = '"' + quote + '"';
        auteur.innerHTML = authorName;
      });
    });
```

```html
<div id="quotes-wrap"></div>
```

The array of quotes for each writer can be accessed using `quotes[writer]`. Next, the key (author's name) for each quote object in the array is obtained using `Object.keys(quoteObj)[0]`, and the value (quote) is obtained using `quoteObj[authorName]`. The auteur and citation elements' innerHTML is then set using these values.

Comment: Thx I think I get it now, I'll tweak around to be sure to know how it works!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is due to how you access the entities as you iterate over them. In your case `writer` will hold the key of the object only, not the name of the author or their quote.

To fix this you can instead use `Object.values()` to get the values from the source which can be flattened in to a single array.

You also have the additional problem that the first item in the array is in a different format to the others, where the author name/quote are the key/value of the object, whereas the others are kept in a more usable format with consistent separated key/values.

To address this you can have some simple logic to check both values if one fails to retrieve the data you require like this - although note that the best solution would be to have all the data in a consistent structure to avoid needing to do this at all.

```js
Object.values(quotes).flat().forEach(item => {
  let author = item.name || Object.keys(item)[0];
  let quote = item.quote || Object.values(item)[0];
 
  // build HTML output...
});
```

Here's a full working example:

```js
const quotes = {karamazov:[{"Serge Karamazov":"Barrez vous **** de mimes."}],abitbol:[{name:"Georges Abitbol",quote:"Le train de tes injures roule sur le rail de mon indiff\xe9rence."}],bath:[{name:"Hubert Bonisseur de la Bath",quote:"\xc7a ne prenait pas beaucoup plus de temps."}],moulinier:[{name:"Moulinier ",quote:"L'habit ne fait pas le moine, mais il fait l'agent... M\xeame non titularis\xe9."}],welles:[{name:"Orson Welles",quote:"C'est du vol et du plagiat. j'aime pas trop les voleurs et..."}]};

const quotesWrap = document.querySelector('#quotes-wrap');

Object.values(quotes).flat().forEach(item => {
  let author = item.name || Object.keys(item)[0];
  let quote = item.quote || Object.values(item)[0];
  createQuoteUi(author, quote);
});

function createQuoteUi(author, quote) {
  const citationWrap = document.createElement("div");
  const citation = document.createElement("p");
  const auteur = document.createElement("p");
  citationWrap.appendChild(citation);
  citationWrap.appendChild(auteur);
  
  citationWrap.classList.add("quote");
  citation.classList.add("citation");
  auteur.classList.add("auteur");
  
  citation.innerHTML = `"${quote}"`;
  auteur.innerHTML = author
  
  quotesWrap.appendChild(citationWrap);
}
```

```css
.quote .citation {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 0;
} 
.quote .auteur {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="quotes-wrap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Js you are trying to access the properties `quote` and `name` directly on the `writer` variable within the loop, writer is just a string representing the keys in the quotes object, not the actual objects containing the quotes.

To access the arrays containing the quotes for each writer, you need to use the quotes object along with the writer key. Then, you can access the first element of each array to get the object containing the quote and name.

```
const quotesWrap = document.querySelector('#quotes-wrap');

Object.keys(quotes).forEach(function(writerKey) {
  const citationWrap = document.createElement("div");
  quotesWrap.appendChild(citationWrap);
  const citation = document.createElement("p");
  const auteur = document.createElement("p");
  citationWrap.appendChild(citation);
  citationWrap.appendChild(auteur);

  citationWrap.classList.add("quote");
  citation.classList.add("citation");
  auteur.classList.add("auteur");

  const writer = quotes[writerKey][0]; // Access the object containing the quote and name
  citation.innerHTML = '"' + writer.quote + '"';
  auteur.innerHTML = writer.name;
});
```

Output:

```
"undefined"

undefined

"Le train de tes injures roule sur le rail de mon indifférence."

Georges Abitbol

"Ça ne prenait pas beaucoup plus de temps."

Hubert Bonisseur de la Bath

"L'habit ne fait pas le moine, mais il fait l'agent... Même non titularisé."

Moulinier

"C'est du vol et du plagiat. j'aime pas trop les voleurs et..."

Orson Welles
```

The first index returns undefined because quotes for `Serge Karamazov` are structured in your quotes `object`. Let us address this specific case where the writers `name` is embedded within the `quote`.